# Django migrating from scratch fails: 'no such table', after adding signal receivers

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-signals

I added some signal receivers to my code and everything was working fine, until I pushed it to version control and the CI/CD pipeline failed. On trying to migrate, it would complain with:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: badges_badge
```

But the migrations were working on my machine!

The CI/CD starts from scratch though, so I tried deleting my `db.sqlite3` locally, then tried to re-migrate with `python manage.py migrate`:

```
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: badges_badge
```

So migrating from an existing db worked, but not from a new one.

My `signals.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from badges.badge_stuff import badges


@receiver(post_save)
def update_badges(sender, **kwargs):
    for badge in badges:
        badge.update()
```

My `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class BadgesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'badges'

    def ready(self):
        # Register signal listeners.
        from . import signals
```

Why would it work with an existing db, but not when initialising it? How to fix this?

Comment: Found this as the (likely) underlying issue for a couple unanswered questions, here I directly explain the actual cause. Questions are: [72445980](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72445980), [66478569](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66478569), and could help people stumbling onto [34548768](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34548768).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue and it was because of how I was registering my signals.

The problem is that the code in `apps.ready()` runs before any migrations, so if `signals.py` depends on models that don't exist in the db yet (e.g. when migrating from scratch), it'll fail. This might happen when your `signals.py` imports other modules which then depend on your models.

Here, `badges.badge_stuff.badges` imports the `Badge` model, which is created on first migration. So it cannot find it.

To fix this, we can use the `post_migrate` signal to register all of our signals *after* any migrations, so any necessary models will be created before any signal code runs.

Modify the above to:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.core.signals import pre_save, post_migrate


class BadgesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'badges'

    def register_signals(self, **kwargs):
        # If your signals are decorated with @receiver, the line below is all you need
        from . import signals
        # Otherwise, explicitly connect the signal handler
        pre_save.connect(signals.my_callback)

    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(self.register_signals, sender=self)
```

And hopefully running your migrations should now work!

Remember to register your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` using this new AppConfig in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'badges.apps.BadgesConfig',
    # Or just 'badges' for Django 4.0+
    ...
]
```